# How can I generate a frequency of 5 GHZ with a crystal

Tags: pll

How can I generate a frequency of 5 GHZ with a crystal

Comment: We are going to need many more details. You have marked it as PCB and manufacturing, are you wanting to make your own crystal? Do you want it to be exactly 5.000 GHz?

Answer (score 8):

Through frequency multiplication, e.g. 50x100MHz, or 100x50MHz etc.

This can be done either directly using [frequency multipliers](http://www.qsl.net/va3iul/Frequency_Multipliers/Frequency_Multipliers.pdf), or indirectly using phase locked loop, and locking 5 GHz oscillator to crystal reference oscillator.

Answer (score 4):

Use one of [these](http://www.analog.com/en/rfif-components/pll-synthesizersvcos/adf4108/products/product.html) PLL chips with a suitable crystal oscillator for the reference signal and one of [these](http://www.crystek.com/microwave/?gclid=CN-N2p7786cCFYFB4Qodt1G7ZA) VCOs. You will need a suitable MCU to configure the PLL chip. It's a standard microwave PLL synthesiser approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the 5 GHz for wireless application you will need to check to see if exactly 5 GHz is required, many times stuff is said to be a certain frequency, but it is actually a slightly different frequency needed. For example, [here](http://parts.digikey.com/1/parts/1390828-osc-vco-5256-5356mhz-smd-5x-5-cvco55bh-5256-5356.html) is a Voltage Control Oscillator (VCO) that can vary between 5.256 and 5.356GHz. These are very useful when trying to get locks on to communication systems.